# How to set DKIM and SPF in Exchanbge mail server

Tags: email, exchange-server, spf, dkim

I have implemented an exchange mail server 2013 . sending email is fine . I want to set different domain for any email as sender which I did that too . Now the problem is that I want to set SPF and DKIM records . My questions :

1 - Do I have to set SPF and DKIM records for any sender domain in my server records ? or they have to be set up on their domains and I need something else when I send emails ?

2 -  Is setting SPF and DKIM records just easy as saving records on server or something in exchange server is needed ?

Comment: Who knows what the business or scenario of the setting of DKIM is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SPF is "envelope sender", "return path", "reverse path",  "bounce
>   address", "2821 FROM", or "MAIL FROM".  RFC5321.MailFrom

So for every domain that has it's own "See definition above" will have to have it's own TYPE 16 (TXT) SPF record in DNS.

DKIM with Exchange - That's a whole different ballgame. I never done it before, but from those I spoke with you have to use a third party tool to do it (Or if you're talented enough code your own). But I would go the proven route and just use one of the solutions below.

https://github.com/Pro/dkim-exchange
https://www.emailarchitect.net/domainkeys/kb/dkim_exchange_2007_2010_2013.aspx

I don't endorse these products, simply because I haven't used them, but I heard they are excellent tools. I also heard some people having a little difficulty setting them up and getting them to work, so test with a [Mail Tester Tool](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/emailauthentication/) just to ensure it's working properly.

Comment: Thanks . Just one thing was vague about private key that where it would be saved on exchange server ?

Answer (score 0):

@henry

I have used this [site](https://postmarkapp.com/guides/dkim)
which dkim should be like that. At first I didn't know how it works. Then I got there are 2 keys . Public and private. The public one should be set on x.com as a TXT record and the private one should be kept at exchange server . The [tool](https://github.com/Pro/dkim-exchange) was helpful . thanks

Just one thing was vague for that and it was the place of storing private key in the exchange server

[image]

Edited :

Comment: The `private` one should be set on x.com as a TXT record - I believe you meant `public` -  The private one will normally be stored in the location the tool that you're using tells you to store it, some of those are configuration where it allows you to specify the location. Some tools store it internally in their own format.  It's all based on which tool you go with.

Comment: @Henry . Oh my bad . Yes the public one